# Cuando intento hacer una llamada Javascript usando xmlrpc con JQuery, obtengo este error

Tags: javascript

> jquery-3.2.1.js:3860 jQuery.Deferred exception: True is not defined
>   ReferenceError: True is not defined
>        at Object. (file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/odoo-js/funciones.js:38:84)
>        at mightThrow (file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/odoo-js/jquery-3.2.1.js:3583:29)
>        at process (file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/odoo-js/jquery-3.2.1.js:3651:12) 
>   undefined jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.2.1.js:3860

Hola,

Esta error, me sale cuando hago una segunda llamada usando xmlrpc contra Odoo. En la primera llamada con xmlrpc al método login, obtengo el uid del usuario. Una vez obtengo el uid, hago una segunda llamada con xmlrpc al método execute_kw para obtener los clientes de dicho uid (tabla res.partner) y en esa segunda llamada es cuando falla el jQuery

```
function autenticar(){  
    var uid;    
    $.when(
        $.xmlrpc({  
            url: 'http://192.168.1.50:8069/xmlrpc/2/common',
            methodName: 'login',
            crossDomain: true,
            params: ['database', 'admin', 'admin'],
            success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {uid = response;},
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) { alert('Error : ' + error.debug ) }
            })
    ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {        
        $.xmlrpc({  
            url: 'http://192.168.1.50:8069/xmlrpc/2/object',
            methodName: 'execute_kw',
            crossDomain: true,
            params: ['database',uid,'admin','res.partner', 'search',[[['is_company', '=', True], ['customer', '=', True]]]],
            success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {alert('segunda_llamada');alert(response);},
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) { alert('Error : ' + error ) }
            })
    });
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías poner que llamada haces, y al de información, así es difícil ayudarte

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, te invito a que hagas el [tour] y sepas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganes tu primer medalla, **es importante que leas [ask]** para que puedas redactar buenas preguntas que sean bien recibidas en la comunidad, saludos !

Comment: Hola Spidvmp, he añadido una explicación más detallada para ver si podéis ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas!

Esto es un disparo al aire, pero me parece que el error con el que te encuentras reside en el `True` que mandas como parámetro. En JavaScript se escribe sin letra capital, en minúsculas: `true`.

Por lo que en la línea:

```
    params: ['database',uid,'admin','res.partner', 'search',[[['is_company', '=', True], ['customer', '=', True]]]],
```

Deberías sustituir `True` por `true`:

```
    params: ['database',uid,'admin','res.partner', 'search',[[['is_company', '=', true], ['customer', '=', true]]]],
```

A no ser que la petición no esté solicitando un booleano directamente si no que quiera el texto `'True'` en cuyo caso sería:

```
    params: ['database',uid,'admin','res.partner', 'search',[[['is_company', '=', 'True'], ['customer', '=', 'True']]]],
```

Comment: Pues has acertado, ya que ahora cambia el error... Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Ahora me da el error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list', por lo que entiendo que en la llamada a function(response, status,jqHXR) el objeto response lo entiende como un String y no es capaz de llenarlo como una lista. ¿Alguna idea de cómo declararlo como lista para que lo lleve automáticamente en la llamada? Gracias por todo

Comment: @SantiagoCarbonell hum... eso no me parece que sea un error `JavaScript`, parece un error de `Python` por lo que el error pudiera estar ocurriendo en el destino de la petición y no a la hora de hacer la petición en sí. Para no desvirtuar la pregunta, creo que lo mejor sería que marcases esta pregunta como resuelta y creases una pregunta diferente con el nuevo problema que estás teniendo.